# Setup Angular Core module - AngularModules

Tags: angular, angular-module

Well, I'm trying to setup an Angular Core Module. I already created the core module and inside the core module I created a Service called Dummy.

`src/app/core/dummy.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DummyService {

  val = 1;
  constructor() { 
    console.log('*** constructor DummyService');
  }
  getNext(): number{
    this.val++;
    return this.val;
  }
}
```

`src/app/core/core.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DummyService } from './dummy.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [DummyService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

`src/app/app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`src/app/app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-template';


  constructor(private dummyService: DummyService) {
    this.dummyService.val = 2;
  }

}
```

And the problem is, that I'm getting this error in my `app.component.ts` constructor:

> No suitable injection token for parameter 'dummyService' of class 'AppComponent'.
> The type should reference a known declaration.(-992003)
> app.component.ts(13, 37): This type could not be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Whe you decore a service as **providedIn: 'root'**, you don't need to add it to the **provider** section of any module.

So, in your *core.module.ts*, this is not need it:

```
 providers: [DummyService]
```

Delete it and try again, please, in order to see if this was the problem.

EDIT: Important! You missed to import your service in your `src/app/app.component.ts` with this:

```
import { DummyService } from '../core/dummy.service';
```

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't answer my question as it's still not working

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, by leaving the providers section in your core.module empty (providers: []), your code seems correct and it should work. Could you please create a stackblitz?

Comment: I have one more error int the app.module.ts: The class 'AppComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.(-996001)

Comment: Here is the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fd2lqk

Comment: Thxs! I'm going to see if I can tell you something more.

Comment: Your code worked right! You only have mistaken in the name of the the method you were using in the service (getDummyData, it didn't exist). I used the "getNext()" method and it worked. See my EDIT and try it my fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sws5jp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yeah but now you import the DummService in the app.component.ts - and I think thats not how Angular Modules work

Comment: The import { XX } from 'yy' is not "the importation", I mean, if you don't declare the service as providedIn'root' (or put it in a providers module section), despite the fact you make import {DummyService}from '../core/dummy.service' in your app.component.ts,it wouldn't work. That import is just to indicate in this piece of code where is the "thing"(service,whatever) you want to use, but you should've it previously loaded (as I said before, with providers or declaring the service as providedIn'root') in order it to work. Try without providedIn 'root' and you're going to see how it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I will reproduce and explain the cause of the error and a solution.

The following should work provided that your definition of `DummyService` is not declared elsewhere in your application scope.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { DummyService } from './dummy.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-template';
  
  constructor(private dummyService: DummyService) {
    this.dummyService.val = 2;
  }
}
```

**Reproducing the error**

> ```
> Error in src/app/app.component.ts (12:23)
> No suitable injection token for parameter 'dummyService' of class 'AppComponent'.
> Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.
> ```

(The above error documented [here](https://angular.io/errors/NG2003) occurs when the type used in the constructor of the class being injected is detected as a primitive type: `string`, `number`, `Object` etc.)

**Code sample that reproduces the error**

Declare an interface type (or even a class) `DummyService` in your app component without declaring or importing the service as shown:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
//import { DummyService } from './dummy.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  constructor(private dummyService: DummyService) {
    this.dummyService.val = 2;
  }
}

export interface DummyService {
  val: number;
}
```

The most likely problem with the code is that the `DummyService` is already declared within your application!

Even if `DummyService` is omitted from the `providers` array in your `Core` module, the above error will occur and precede the common injection error (see below).

Next, add the `DummyService` to the providers array in your `Core` module.

Excluding the service from the `providers` array will lead to the following error:

> ```
> ERROR
> Error: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[DummyService -> DummyService -> DummyService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for DummyService!
> ```

The above error documented [here](https://angular.io/errors/NG0201) refers to a missing provider for the injected class.

To recify the above issues, just remove an existing non-service declaration of `DummyService` and
add the service class to the `providers` array in the `Core` module.